# Disable Settings.bundle in iOS app when Development Build is untick in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have some preferences which I use only in in development app and I want to remove them from the final build, i tried the following

```
// C# example:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
using System.IO;

public class iOSBuildPostprocessor
{    
    [PostProcessBuild]
    public static void ChangeXcodePlist(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuiltProject)
    {
#if !DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
        var path = pathToBuiltProject + "/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Settings.bundle/Root.plist";
        PlistDocument settings = new PlistDocument();
        settings.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(path));
        rootDict = settings.root;
        rootDict.CreateArray("PreferenceSpecifiers");

        File.WriteAllText(path, settings.WriteToString());
#ENDIF
    }
}
```

but i discovered that DEVELOPMENT_BUILD is defined only in the player, does exist a way to automate this step at building time?

Answer (score 0):

I solved implementing IPostprocessBuildWithReport instead of using PostProcessBuild attribute:

```
    public void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
    {

        if ((report.summary.platform == BuildTarget.iOS) &&((report.summary.options & BuildOptions.Development) == 0))
        {
            Debug.Log("It isn't development");
            var path = report.summary.outputPath + "/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Settings.bundle/Root.plist";

            PlistDocument settings = new PlistDocument();
            settings.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(path));
            rootDict = settings.root;
            rootDict.CreateArray("PreferenceSpecifiers");

            File.WriteAllText(path, settings.WriteToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("It's' development");
        }
   }
```